# Check for variable before foreach loop, shorthand?

Tags: php

I have code set up like the following often:

```
if ($arr) {
    foreach ($arr as $a) {
        // Code stuffs
    }
}
```

If `$arr` doesn't exist, it doesn't matter in the slightest, so I'm tempted to use everybody's favorite suppressor (`@`) rather than muck up my code with that if statement.

- Is there some kind of shorthand to do that if check and foreach on the same line?
- Any huge issue with suppressing the error in this context?

Comment: How do you even get in a situation where "`$arr` doesn't exist [and] it doesn't matter in the slightest"? That feels very sloppy.

Comment: In this case a method is returning false. Is there a question I should be asking to avoid this situation? Return an empty array instead?

Comment: It depends. Does it make more sense as a "false" flag or as an empty list? in this case, i'd say it makes more sense as an empty list.

Comment: Is there a logical reason to return `false` instead of an empty array? If there is none, an empty array would be much easier. See also [Fables for the Software Engineer: Empty](http://thecodelesscode.com/case/6).

Comment: I suppose there isn't. Thanks guys/gals, this has been very helpful, aside from the demoralizing downvote - larger problem solved :D

Comment: @Chords Remember to accept your favourite answer tomorrow!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'd suggest an alternative approach, which is derived by my C++ and Java formation during school years.

**If you're in doubt, initialize the variable if it's cheap to do so.**

for example in your case I'd to the following

```
//early on, *before any other possible use of $arr*!
$arr = array();
//do something else, remake $arr or not, whatever!
foreach ($arr as $a) {
    // Code stuffs
}
```

correct, simple, readable and understandable at a glance. If you don't initialize $arr before, you may wonder WHERE it's born... expecially after 6 months after you closed this project and need some debug!

Comment: I'd rather say "initialize the variable, no matter if you're in doubt or not"

Comment: Yeah @YourCommonSense i agree completely... but i left the possibility to consider object initializations that may be expensive and should be avoided unless absolutely necessary. Anyway, I'm more of the "always initialize" team.

Answer (score 3):

You could always do a "shorthand" function

```
function checkArr($arr){
    return isset($arr) ? ((count($arr) > 0) ? $arr : array()) : array();
}

foreach(checkArr($arr) as $a){
    echo $a;
}
```

My 2¢.

Comment: Isn't this like killing a kitten with a bazooka? yes it gets the work done... but why do you need to kill the kitten in the first place???

Comment: I always let all notices on to see all "errors", `isset` and `count` are always killing me :). I use that function even if I didn't initialize the array in the first place.

Comment: Well, if that's so for you i guess that my answer might help you in that regard.

Comment: I know how to initialize an array, but sometimes I forget to initialize it, or I stumble upon a code that I didn't makethat are over 10-15k of lines and it has tons of initialized arrays, they are a pain. Searching over a huge class jumps me to another function. I prefer to check it and leave it like that :)

Comment: You really need to think about some refactoring if you have a 10-15k lines code in that manner

Comment: @RoyalBg tell that to API developers for flights and accommodation booking that make API's a huge pain.

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
if ((!isset($arr)) || (!is_array($arr)) $arr = array();

foreach ($arr as $a) 
{
        // Code stuffs
}
```

I know, that `if` is still there, but you dont have the whole loop in it

Comment: could also be `foreach(!isset($arr) ? array() : $arr as $a)`

Comment: you need to check if $arr is array too

Comment: Yes of course, but the imbricated `foreach` in `if` is even more readable and does not causes any issue. I was thinking the OP would want the shorter code possible.

Answer (score -2):

You can write something like this:

```
foreach((array)$arr as $a) {
    // ...
}
```

Cast undefined variable to array will produce an empty array. This won't work when $arr value is type of boolean i.e. false.

Comment: You can, but you shouldn't.